# Polar/height/radial plot

Tags: plotting

I have a function $f(r,\psi)$ and I would like to plot it on a circle such that the the radial direction indicates the change of the function as a function of $r$; the angular direction the change of the function as a function of $\psi$ and finally the height the actual value of the function.

Which plotting routine should I use for this?

Comment: Probably `ParametricPlot3D` can you supply any function? Or more likely `Plot3D`, I'm not sure I got 'on a cricle'. Anyway you can make use of `CoordinateTransform`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick mockup of Kuba's suggestion using a function I made up:

```
f[r_, θ_] := Sin[3*θ]^3/(r + 5);

ParametricPlot3D[
 {x, y, f[Sequence @@ ToPolarCoordinates[{x, y}]]}
 , {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}
 , PlotRange -> All
 , MeshFunctions -> {Abs[#1 + I #2] &, Arg[#1 + I #2] &}(*This produces the polar mesh.*)
 , RegionFunction -> ((#1^2 + #2^2 < 1) &) (*You can eliminate this if you want the region to be rectangular.*)
 ]
```

This will produce the following plot:

[image]